# Is there a specific meaning for these arrows in the architecture of a microcontroller?

Tags: symbol, architecture

[image]

1. Yellow mark
2. Green mark
3. Blue mark

Do these arrow signs mean something specific? Also, if there are other types, where can I go to read about them?

Source : [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc2540.pdf?ts=1648786274233&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)

Edited :
[image]

Comment: Such a graphical drawing is an abstraction; used solely to convey "block overview" information and should not be taken literally.  These can't be taken literally because what is actually happening is way more complicated.  This is a generalization of operation, to give a fast and good idea of how and what this thing does, without drawing a hundred pages of schematics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single line (3), (2) means the data is one logic connection. The wider arrow (1) implies a data bus of some number of individual connections.

If the end arrows go both ways, then the data flow can be bidirectional. If the arrow goes in only one direction then the data flows only in that direction.

In this case, either the RESET_N input or the watchdog timer can cause a reset, but the reset cannot affect the RESET_N pin or the watchdog timer. One of the XOSC pins is only an input and one is only an output.

Comment: One more thing I missed to mark. In the SFR bus (upwards), it just going only outwards. While "WATCHDOG TIMER", "CLOCK MUX and CALIBRATION", "SLEEP TIMER" & "POWER MANAGEMENT CONTROLLER" goes two ways with the SFR BUS. What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: The SFR bus arrow is just to indicate that this is a bus that can have many things attached to it so it could continue upwards if there were more blocks.   The other bidirectional arrows imply that, for example, the POWER MANAGEMENT CONTROLLER can be read from or written to via the SFR bus.

Comment: And "MEMORY ARBITRATOR" can only write to "SFR BUS"

Comment: Ah, I think "MEMORY ARBITRATOR" controls the SFR bus, since it runs "through" from top to bottom in the original artwork. I would not take these diagrams too seriously, they should give an idea, but I would expect some omissions and (more rarely) errors from time to time, the real information is elsewhere.